# Swiftui Notifications time interval least 60

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an Islamic application for calculating prayers, the notification does not work, I can not understand why. I use this code in Xcode 12.3

```
 func scheduleNotification(prayers: PrayerTimes) {
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let dateSelected = prayer?.isha
    guard let selectedDate = dateSelected else {
            return
        }

    let interval = -selectedDate.timeIntervalSinceNow

        guard interval > 0 else {
            return
        }
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Вермя молитвы"
content.body = "Пора совершать намаз"
content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "alarm", content: content, trigger: trigger)
center.add(request)
}
```

in my PrayerTimeViewModel I have

```
 @Published var times: PrayerTimes?
 func getPrayerTime() {
    let cal = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let date = cal.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
    let coordinates = Coordinates(latitude: lm.location?.latitude ?? 0.0, longitude: lm.location?.longitude ?? 0.0)
    var par = method.params
    par.madhab = mashab
    self.times = PrayerTimes(coordinates: coordinates, date: date, calculationParameters: par)
}
```

and my View Toggle

```
 Toggle("", isOn: $notif.notificationsEnabled)
                        .onChange(of: notif.notificationsEnabled) { (value) in
                            if notif.notificationsEnabled == true {
                            notif.requestPermission()
                                notif.scheduleNotification(prayers: model.times!)
                            } else {
                                notif.removeNotifications()
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your maths is out. The calculated TimeInterval (for a FUTURE date) is negated, thus you are (would be) setting the Trigger to be in the past.
But worse, because you have defensively coded (Good Job!) to 'avoid' this exact situation, the LocalNotification code is never run.

Change this line:  let interval = -selectedDate.timeIntervalSinceNow

```
let interval = selectedDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
```